# Insert LongType to Cassandra using thrift failed

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra, thrift

I tried to insert a longtype column into cassandra:

```
     Column docid = new Column();        
     docid.setName("docid".getBytes());      
     ByteBuffer val = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
     val.putLong(123111111111111111L);
     docid.setValue(val);
     docid.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
     client.insert(term, parent, docid, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
```

It runs OK but when I tried to get the value by CLI, it returns

```
[default@Test] get Term[utf8('hello')]['docid'] as long;
=> (column=docid, value=, timestamp=1362891987234)
```

It seems that value is not correctly inserted. Why?

I tried insert ascii type and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
docid.setValue(val);
```

To:

```
docid.setValue(val.array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already found the solution, or maybe you switched to CQL but that can help :

After putting your long value into the ByteBuffer, you forgot to **flip()** it.
As explained in the javadoc, flipping the buffer means *setting the limit to the current position, and then set the current position to zero*.

If you don't flip it, the contained value is read starting from the current position (which is right after the bytes you inserted), that's why the "value" is empty when you query it.

Here's the fixed code :

```
val.putLong(123111111111111111L);
val.flip(); // Flip the buffer
docid.setValue(val);
```

**EDIT :**

`val.array()` returns the ByteBuffer's internal array, so instead of flipping the buffer, setting the column's value to `val.array()` may also work (but **only** if the byte buffer is not directly allocated)